# Angular Dynamically generated ID locate for event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

With jQuery I can locate and ID start with "conditionValue"

```
$(document).on('focus', "[id^=conditionValue]", function (event) {
    // code
});
```

How do I find an ID starting with say "conditionValue" in Angular.  I will probably want a button click event.

Thus this will not work below because it will only start with `conditionValue` and be more like  `conditionValue434`.

THUS this code below needs modified.

```
$scope.conditionValue= function () {
    // code 
};
```

Comment: What version of angular are you using? Angular comes shipped with jQuery lite (jqLite) so you can do it like you usually do in jQuery. Usually this isn't the recommended approach. You need to provide some more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to handle a click event, the AngularJS way is to use the `ng-click` directive.

Thus, your HTML code will be:

```
<div id="conditionValue434" data-ng-click="myClickEventHandler($event)"></div>
```

And in your controller, you will then define your click event handler:

```
$scope.myClickEventHandler = function (evt) {
    //evt is the jQuery event object or the jQLite object
    //Some code here
};
```

However, if what you intend to do is add a click event handler to a DOM element that may or may not exist and that you specifically need to listen to events for a DOM element, the AngularJS way is to create a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).
The reference mentioned above has excellent examples to get your started.

Comment: Perfect that works.  How can I get the value of the dynamically generated ID?      so inside here $scope.myClickEventHandler = function () {
    //Some code here
};  thx

Comment: I have edited my code to add the event object. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-). You can use that object to get more information on the target.